# Conda activation

Tags: conda

I recently moved miniconda2 to another directory and now I can't activate the conda environment. Please any suggestion to resolve this problem.

```
bash: conda: command not found
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I said initially is wrong, amending PATH will not suffice.

If the [anaconda documentation](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/move-directory/) is something to go by. You can't just move directories.

You will have to uninstall conda and reinstall to the new place.

Comment: don't forget to substitute `/new/path/to/conda` with where you actually put miniconda2

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually it keeps looking for conda in the old directory. How can I change the path in bash please.

Comment: With the command that I put in the answer, but please don't just copy and paste, but actually read through the linked article first. That might make things clearer

Comment: or are you saying, that it looks in the old dir even though you did that?

Comment: Yes it keeps looking in the old directory even though I did that.

Comment: amended my answer, TL;DR you have to reinstall, see here https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/move-directory/

Comment: Thank you. I'm checking that.